# IPN return invalid sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have this IPN listener script. I jst copy this from the paypal and modify a little.

```
   function ipn_listener()
    {

        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
        if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }
        // read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        } 
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) { 
        if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
        } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";

        }
        // STEP 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate

        $ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

        // In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
        // please download 'cacert.pem' from [link removed] and set 
        // the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');

        if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
        // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
            echo "Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data";
        curl_close($ch);
        exit;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        // STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
        switch($res){
            case "VERIFIED":
            echo 'verified';
                break;
            case "INVALID":
              echo 'invalid';
                break;
            default:
                // any other case (such as no response, connection timeout...)
        }
    }
```

everytime i call that listener it always return invalid. I dont understand the problem..it is just my 1st time using IPN.. Need help i want to display the IPN message.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling that listener or Paypal does?
This script should be executed after a transfer happened.

If i`m right then you should specify the url to this file/function in your PayPal Profile and check again your html code, so that the POST action is right. About this check more here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/

Check more here about the ipn listener https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: im calling the listener..about the `echo "Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data";` i think that only output when there is an error on curl.

Comment: Check the IPN history if there all is fine. 
My account -> History -> IPN History

And also verify if you are really using the sandbox.

Comment: i already check and everything went well...delivery status is 'sent'. even I try the simulation IPN, it will also sent successfully. The only thing I don't understand is why I always receive invalid.